# Skyscraper sheaf?

Tags: sheaf-theory, visualization, sheaf-cohomology

I was wondering whether someone could provide me with an easy definition of a skyscraper sheaf and, more importantly, with a visualization of it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

This is my take: a skyscraper sheaf $\mathcal F$ on a topological space $X$ is given by a specific point $x\in X$ and a ring/group/whatever $A$.

We then have, for any open $U\subseteq X$, that $$\mathcal F(U)=\cases{0& if $x\notin U$\\A& if $x\in U$}$$ So it's basically saying "Everything that matters about this sheaf is in the point $x$", hence the idea that you've placed a lone skyscraper at the point $x$, which is where the name comes from.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is....when thinking about the stalk of that point, is it to be taken as finite (a set with a finite number of elements-objects-points) or rather as infinite (with an open number of elements)? I hope my question makes sense to you.

Comment: @JavierArias The stalk of $\mathcal F$ at $x$ is just $A$. At any other point $y$, it depends on whether all open neighbourhoods of $y$ contain $x$ or not, and it's $A$ or $0$ correspondingly. So it really depends on the topology. If $x$ is a closed point, then it is truly localised at just $x$.

Comment: @Arthur- Ok. Thanks.